# Group objects sharing same key and cast them in another object

Tags: c#, .net, linq

These are my classes:

```
class Schedule
{
    Int32 Id {get; set;}
    String CustomerName {get; set;}
    DateTime SchedStartDate {get; set;}
    DateTime SchedEndDate {get; set;}
    List<Body> Body {get; set;}
}

class Body
{
    Int32 Id {get; set;}
    String ProductBarcode {get; set;}
    Int32 ProductItemId {get; set;}
    DateTime DtEvaluation {get; set;}
    List<History> History {get; set;}
}

class History
{
    Int32 ActionId { get; set; }
    String Description { get; set; }
    String Picture { get; set; }
    String Observation { get; set; }
    Int32 EvalItemId { get; set; }
    Int32 EvalCriteriaId { get; set; }
}
```

I have an `Schedule` object and the string `Body.ProductBarcode` is repeated on the `Schedule.Body` list. Also, sometimes the list `Body.History` is empty and sometimes it is not.

The `Body.ProductBarcode` repetition is correct from the application's point of view, but it is giving  me some trouble when I try to consolidate the data, as I want it to be cast the `Schedule` object in another class (that I find easier to work with):

```
class EmailSchedule
{
    String Id { get; set; }
    Int32 ProductId { get; set; }
    DateTime DtEvaluation { get; set; }
    List<EmailHistory> History { get; set; }
}
class EmailHistory
{
    Int32 ActionId { get; set; }
    String Description { get; set; }
    String Picture { get; set; }
    String Observation { get; set; }
    String EvalItemId { get; set; }
    Int32 EvalCriteriaId { get; set; }
}
```

Keep in mind that, at this point, the only thing that interests me is the `Body.ProductBarcode` key and each of it's `Body.History` lists. `Schedules`'s properties are already safe and sound and the other `Body`'s properties are useless.

[This is an example](https://pastebin.com/byjUawDD) of a JSON that will be converted into the `Schedule` object

My problem is that, as there are repeated `Body.ProductBarcode` I need to group the occurrences where the `Body.ProductBarcode` match and, after that bring all the `Body.History` lists to the same `EmailSchedule.History` list.

I've tried to use [**LINQ**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), but as I'm not familiar with it, I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: When you say "group" and "bring", what do you mean exactly? How do you group `ProductItemId` or `DtEvaluation` if they are different ?

Comment: I've edited the question. The only property that matter at this point is `Body.ProductBarcode`. The other properties are useless.

Comment: So in your new `EmailSchedule` object, you don't mind if `ProductId` and `DtEvaluation` are null or zero?

Answer (score 1):

I am still not 100% sure what structure you're looking for, but could you try this and let me know if its anywhere close to what you want?

Based on your feedback I can tweak it. (schd is your schedule object)

```
var scheduleList = schd.Body.GroupBy(b => b.ProductBarcode).Select(b => b.Select(bod => new EmailSchedule
{
    Id = s.Id.ToString(),
    DtEvaluation = bod.DtEvaluation,
    ProductId = bod.ProductItemId,
    History = bod.History
})).SelectMany(b => b);      //flatten to single list
```

p.s. for your classes, using `public` would be good since otherwise it won't deserialize from json, and since the `EmailHistory` and `History` classes are identical, I just use `History`. If you actually do need to cast it to `EmailHistory`, you'd need to add code to the line `History = bod.History`.

Comment: It did not work... The scheduleList's results were not grouped.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't care about any of the `EmailSchedule` properties since you said the other `Body` properties are useless besides `History`. You can copy the other `History` properties to `EmailHistory` in the same way I did here if you need all of them.

Here is the mixed query/method syntax:

```
var ans = from b in bodies
          group b by b.ProductBarcode into bg
          let bgf = bg.First()
          select new EmailSchedule {
              History = bg.SelectMany(b => b.History, (b, h) => new EmailHistory { ActionId = h.ActionId, Description = h.Description }).ToList()
          };
```

and here is query syntax:

```
var ans = from b in bodies
          group b by b.ProductBarcode into bg
          let bgf = bg.First()
           select new EmailSchedule {
               History = (from b in bg from h in b.History select new EmailHistory { ActionId = h.ActionId, Description = h.Description }).ToList()
          };
```